# FullscreenBehaviour for Mahapps

Tags: c#, wpf, fullscreen, mahapps.metro

How to add a dynamic switching ability from fullscreen to windowed mode and vice versa to Mahapps MetroWindow?

Starting with Normal Window

[image: Initially windowed state]

and after switching to fullscreen the top right window Buttons (Minimize/Maximize/Close) are still visible (but they shouldn't be visible as well as the title bar). The reserved space for the title bar seems to be still there.

[image: Buttons still visible after switching to fullscreen]

The other way round initially from fullscreen state (no buttons, except the Hello button in the middle and no title bar => as expected)

[image]

... but when switching back to normal window state the title is back again but the top left buttons are missing.

[image]

Am I doing something wrong here in the code? I used an derrived Behaviour. The interesting part that is executed when switching is this:

```
    private static void OnIsFullscreenChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var window = (MetroWindow)sender;

        var oldValue = (bool)e.OldValue;
        var newValue = (bool)e.NewValue;

        if (newValue == oldValue || window == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (newValue)
        {
            window.Tag = window.WindowState;

            window.Topmost = true;

            window.UseNoneWindowStyle = true;
            window.IgnoreTaskbarOnMaximize = true;
            window.ShowTitleBar = false;

            window.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
            window.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
        }
        else
        {
            window.Topmost = false;

            window.UseNoneWindowStyle = false;
            window.IgnoreTaskbarOnMaximize = false;
            window.ShowTitleBar = true;

            window.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.SingleBorderWindow;
            window.WindowState = (WindowState)window.Tag;
        }
    }
```

Attaching a simular Behaviour to a default Window WPF control everything works as expected.

I attach the Behaviour this way:

```
<controls:MetroWindow ... local:FullscreenBehavior.IsFullscreen="{Binding Fullscreen}">
<!-- code above sets initial state depending on ViewModel value -->
<!-- code below fires mode switching when a defined key is pressed => executes  OnIsFullscreenChanged method -->
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <behaviours:BorderlessWindowBehavior />
        <behaviours:WindowsSettingBehaviour />
        <behaviours:GlowWindowBehavior />
        <modern:FullscreenBehavior FullscreenKey="{Binding FullscreenKey}" />       
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    ...
```

**EDIT: Set state of Window Buttons explicitly**
When I extend the method to set the states to the correct value explicitly there seems to be another strange effect:

```
    private static void OnIsFullscreenChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var window = (MetroWindow)sender;

        var oldValue = (bool)e.OldValue;
        var newValue = (bool)e.NewValue;

        if (newValue == oldValue || window == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (newValue)
        {
            window.Tag = window.WindowState;

            window.Topmost = true;

            window.UseNoneWindowStyle = true;
            window.IgnoreTaskbarOnMaximize = true;
            window.ShowTitleBar = false;
            window.ShowCloseButton = false;
            window.ShowMaxRestoreButton = false;
            window.ShowMinButton = false;

            window.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
            window.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
        }
        else
        {
            window.Topmost = false;

            window.UseNoneWindowStyle = false;
            window.IgnoreTaskbarOnMaximize = false;
            window.ShowTitleBar = true;
            window.ShowCloseButton = true;
            window.ShowMaxRestoreButton = true;
            window.ShowMinButton = true;

            window.ShowCloseButton = true;
            window.ShowMaxRestoreButton = true;
            window.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.SingleBorderWindow;
            window.WindowState = (WindowState)window.Tag;
        }
    }
```

The window gets "sometimes" cut at the border and sometimes it looks right (like in the first picture at the top).
Also I don't know (yet) wheter the space of the title bar is no longer reserved when initially starting with fullscreen (there seems to be a difference, don't know why).

[image]

Comment: What's the value of  ShowCloseButton, ShowMaxRestoreButton, ShowMinButton properties?

Comment: @FDL: I have not set them explicitly. As you can see they are shown if I start with normal window, but when starting with fullscreen they are hidden.

Comment: @FDL: If I set them to false/hidden... will this also remove the space for the titlebar?

Comment: I don't think so. But I'm sure you have to manage the ResizeMode too. Try with the quick start: http://mahapps.com/guides/quick-start.html

Comment: @Beachwalker to work correct with the non windows style, don't change the original `WindowStyle` just set only the `UseNoneWindowStyle`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a little bug in the current 1.0 release. If you toggle the `UseNoneWindowStyle`, it doesn't bring back the buttons and toolbar. I'll fix this as soon as possible.

So, here is a little workaround for you.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ToggleFullScreenProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("ToggleFullScreen",
                                typeof(bool),
                                typeof(MainWindow),
                                new PropertyMetadata(default(bool), ToggleFullScreenPropertyChangedCallback));

private static void ToggleFullScreenPropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var metroWindow = (MetroWindow)dependencyObject;
    if (e.OldValue != e.NewValue)
    {
        var fullScreen = (bool)e.NewValue;
        if (fullScreen)
        {
            metroWindow.UseNoneWindowStyle = true;
            metroWindow.IgnoreTaskbarOnMaximize = true;
            metroWindow.ShowMinButton = false;
            metroWindow.ShowMaxRestoreButton = false;
            metroWindow.ShowCloseButton = false;
            metroWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
        }
        else
        {
            metroWindow.UseNoneWindowStyle = false;
            metroWindow.ShowTitleBar = true; // <-- this must be set to true
            metroWindow.IgnoreTaskbarOnMaximize = false;
            metroWindow.ShowMinButton = true;
            metroWindow.ShowMaxRestoreButton = true;
            metroWindow.ShowCloseButton = true;
            metroWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
        }
    }
}

public bool ToggleFullScreen
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(ToggleFullScreenProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ToggleFullScreenProperty, value); }
}
```

Hope this helps.