# StickWindow in Mahapps

Tags: wpf, mahapps.metro

I'm trying to implement snapping to edges. I've found one answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1587439/1830639) and implemented, however it destroys the chromeless window of Mahapps MetroWindow.

I've adapted the solution to use Behaviors, so I'm going to share only the Behavior snnipet (you can find StickyWindow code [here](http://programminghacks.net/2009/10/19/download-snapping-sticky-magnetic-windows-for-wpf/)):

**Usage**:

```
<metro:MetroWindow
x:Class="Communicator.Main.Views.ShellView"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
xmlns:metro="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
xmlns:phoneView="clr-namespace:Communicator.Softphone.Views;assembly=Communicator.Softphone"
xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:Communicator.ControlLibrary.Converters;assembly=Communicator.ControlLibrary"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Communicator.Main"
Title="Comunicador" Height="600" Width="450"
WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" ResizeMode="NoResize" TitlebarHeight="40"
EnableDWMDropShadow="True" WindowTransitionsEnabled="False"
cal:Message.Attach="[Event KeyDown] = [Action KeyDown($executionContext)]; [Event Activated] = [Action ViewActivated]; [Event Deactivated] = [Action ViewDeactivated]">
<i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <local:StickyWindowBehavior />
</i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

**StickWindowBehavior**:

```
public class StickyWindowBehavior : Behavior<Window>
{
    private StickyWindow stickWindow = null;

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        stickWindow = new StickyWindow(AssociatedObject)
        {
            StickToScreen = true,
            StickOnResize = true,
            StickOnMove = true
        };
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        if (stickWindow != null)
            stickWindow.ReleaseHandle();
    }
}
```

What happens to my MetroWindow:

[image]

How can I add the stick behavior without losing the chromeless window of MetroWindow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is caused by the same reason as in [Attaching Behaviour to MetroWindow fails and results in wrong Style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28013132/attaching-behaviour-to-metrowindow-fails-and-results-in-wrong-style/28013525#28013525): **Mahapps.Metro** sets its behaviours in the window's style, so actually you're overriding those declarations in your XAML.

You have to set the standard behaviours along with your own:

```xml
<i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <local:StickyWindowBehavior />
    <Behaviours:BorderlessWindowBehavior />
    <Behaviours:WindowsSettingBehaviour />
    <Behaviours:GlowWindowBehavior />
</i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```